# How can I remove the ascii character x02 from my string with php?

Tags: php, regex, ascii

I have tried a lot of things but nothing happens. My generated xml is not well formed because of the ascii character x02 (in VIM it is '^B'). I have tried it with the following line:

```
$keywords = preg_replace('/\x02/', '', $keywords);
```

But that won't work. Do you have an idea?

Comment: Try replacing the single quote with double quotes `"/\0x2/"`

Answer (score 4):

Why use regexp?

```
str_replace(chr(2),'',$keywords);
```

Comment: i started with string replace but it did not work. now i kno why...i looked at the wrong place... -.- sorry for wasting your time and thank you for fast answering!

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `"` for using escape sequences. Replace your code with:

```
$keywords = preg_replace("/\x02/", '', $keywords);
```